# Powershell - Format Jagged Array Output

Tags: powershell

So I would think that this would be a simple thing to do with powershell, but I can't seem to figure out how to make my array output as columns. Below is my script.

```
$Table = @()

$Employees = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Emplyoees,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -Filter * -Properties * | ?{$_.telephoneNumber -ne $Null}

ForEach($User in $Employees){$Table += @($User.Name,$user.telephoneNumber)}

($Table)
```

The output looks similar to:

User1
PhoneNumber1
User2
PhoneNumber2

What I would like it to look like is:

Name        PhoneNumber
User1        PhoneNumber1
User2        PhoneNumber2

Any help would be amazing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ForEach($User in $Employees){$Table += ,@($User.Name,$user.telephoneNumber)} #NOTE THE COMMA HERE
$table | % { $_ -join '`t' } # the `t is a tab, but you can use whatever you want
```

Edit after comment:

if is just needed a layout  you can try:

```
 $table | % {  "{0,-20}{1,20}" -f $_[0],$_[1]  } #the 2nd value in {} is the relative cursor position the sign left o right alignment
```

but why not use just `$Employees` variable to show the result:

```
$Employees = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Emplyoees,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -Filter * -Properties * | 
?{$_.telephoneNumber -ne $Null} | select name, telephonenumber | ft
```

Comment: Kind of. I had to switch to doublequotes instead of singlequotes. Also the only issue is that since everyones name is a different length, the tabs don't make the telephone numbers lineup properly. Also before anyone asks, im outputting to a array because I will be adding a 3rd column once i get this to work.

Comment: @YuriOlinares I've added other solutions, you may need to adjust them based on future added columns

Comment: An array is a bad way to do this. Use the objects that PowerShell likes so much. Try C.B.'s last code with `ft -autosize` as the end. It will try to adjust the columns to show the full length of the values

Comment: Thank you for your input C.B, in the end i realized that i was trying to make this look pretty in a powershell window when the end result would be to copy and paste the results into an excel doc and then email it off to a manager. So as long as i can get all the info seperated by commas - will accomplish with a -join "," then i can pop it into excel no problem